# Update the code and commit/push it to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I've forked an app from heroku and have it's code , now I want to make some changes in that code and want to redeploy it as my forked app and want to see the changes in the forked app not on the original app from where i've forked it, I am using this URL for that but it is not working for me URL is `http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/09/rails-update-source-existing-app-heroku/`
I am not able to redeploy it on heroku.
Please suggest me what to do, Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the output of `git remote -v` in the new version of the code just so I can tell what you've done - you can replace the application names.

Comment: Output of 'git remote -v is' :                                     heroku git@heroku.work:tranquil-basin-9139.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.work:tranquil-basin-9139.git (push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from what I can see you've pulled down the application `tranquil-basic-9139` from Heroku. The simplest way to push this to a new application is to do `git remote rm heroku` which will disconnect this `heroku` remote from the application and then if you do a `heroku create` it would create a new application on Heroku and add a new Heroku remote pointing at the new application allowing you to do `git push heroku` to push to the new application.